# Difference between narrowing and truncation in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, truncation, narrowing

I've been going through a book (C++ Programming Language Stroustrup 4th ed).
An example given in a section related to Initialization as below:

```
void f(double d, int i)
{
    int a{ d };     // error : possible truncation
    char b{ i };    // error : possible narrowing
}
```

What exactly is the difference between truncation and narrowing?

Comment: Narrowing for characters truncation for float -> integers? Think that's pretty much it

Comment: @AlanBirtles, is there some generic explanation about these two words, not just in the above example code context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A narrowing conversion is basically any conversion that may cause a loss of information. Strictly speaking, a [narrowing conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#7) is :

> an implicit conversion
>
> - from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
> - from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type, or
> - from a pointer type or a pointer-to-member type to bool.

Notice that this means both of the conversions you posted are narrowing conversion. `int a{ d };` is the first case and `char b{ i };` is the fourth.

Truncation only occurs when converting between a floating point type and an integer type. It generally refers to the decimal portion of the floating point number being lost ([source](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.fpint#:truncation)). This implies that truncation is a subset of narrowing conversions.

Comment: thank you, this cleared my understanding. Just another query, does the c++ standard mention any of these two words?

Comment: @pasha Both of the links in my answer are direct links to the definitions of these terms in the c++ standard. Repeated here : [narrowing conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#7) and [truncation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.fpint#:truncation).

Comment: my bad, i thought it's just some document on github, thanks again

Comment: @pasha Technically, it is just some document on github. It isn't an official published version of the standard. It's an up to date working draft for the next version of the standard. But it's free and still very accurate, it was last updated Friday.

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly is the difference between truncation and narrowing?

**Truncation** shortens a decimal-based value such as a `float` or a `double` to its integral form `int` with the extra precision bits after the decimal (from 2<sup>-1</sup> in corresponding decimal form) removed.

A `double` can be truncated to a `float` as well, with the possibility of an overflow (depending on size of the value) and removal of half of the precision bits in its binary form (since double has twice the precision of float, with them ordinally being 64 and 32 bit floating points respectively).

For an example of `double` being truncated into a `float`, consider something which goes atleast above 23 precision bits (considering the mantissa of float) such as the value of PI, regarding which BenVoigt gave an example in the comments.

The value of PI as given by a double is:

```cpp
11.001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000
// 3.141592653589793116
```

Note that there are 52 precision bits (according to IEEE 754 standard, from 0 to 51), or the bits forming the value after the decimal.

Corresponding truncated float value:

```cpp
11.0010010000111111011011
// 3.1415927410125732422
```

Note the inaccuracy for the value of PI in relative terms of the number considered above. This is caused by the removal of the trailing bits of precision when truncating the value from `double` to `float` (which has only 23 precision bits, from 0 to 22), ordinally decreasing the precision bits in this case.

Following the conversion of floating-point values to integral form, you can say it acts similar to a `floor` function call.

**Narrowing** is shortening of the value as the name implies as well, but unlike truncation it is not restricted to shortening of a floating-point value to an integer value. It applies to other conversions as well, such as a `long` to an `int`, a pointer type to a boolean and a character to an integer (as in your example).

Comment: double->float also involves truncation (and possibly overflow)

Comment: @BenVoigt Corrected, also does the end result of that truncation result in an integral value or floating-point one? (overflow would occur)

Comment: Also would like to be certain - does a truncation only refer to conversion from floating-point values, or can it be from non-decimal values as well, such as from an `int` to a `short`?

Comment: It'll be a new floating-point value, but with fewer trailing bits of precision.  "Truncation" simply means removing bits of precision.  Often truncation takes place at the integer boundary ("decimal point") but it doesn't have to.

Comment: From an int to short typically loses the most significant bits (and for `unsigned int` to `unsigned short` is guaranteed to do so) so it has no effect on precision only on range.  It's not truncation because you aren't losing trailing bits.

Comment: @BenVoigt so in other words when a shorter-ranged variable is assigned to a longer one, it is not truncated, following it has no effect on the change of values after the decimal point, right?. Only the lower bits would be copied then I suppose. Can you provide an example of truncating a value not at the integer boundary?

Comment: For example, PI in a double-precision floating point variable (`double` in C++) is 3.141592653589793116 and in a single-precision floating point variable (`float` in C++)
3.1415927410125732422.  What?  That has more digits.  Yes more decimal digits.  But the binary (note: not the IEEE representation, these are just binary positional notation) values are  `11.001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000` and `11.0010010000111111011011`   As you can see the second value is rounded off with many fewer bits of precision.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yep I know double and float are x2 and x1 precision respectively. Nice example - so the value in binary is cut off or the extra precision bits of double are taken off, which leads to a float value of Pi which is incorrect as rounded-off from the double, gotcha thanks! Mind if I incorporate that example in my answer?

Comment: Go right ahead and use the example as you please.  Note that it isn't "double is correct and float is not"... PI is an irrational number that cannot be exactly specified regardless of precision.  The closest `double` is naturally more precise than the closest `float`, but both do have quantization error.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes correct, but I was pertaining to 'correctness' in terms of the relative value, considering the value of PI upto the decimal places given by the double value, for which the truncated float in turn has incorrect value due to scraping of the precision bits. I do know that both are incorrect, and in this sense we can say that the double gives an incorrect approximated value, but the float gives a further incorrect one, due to the truncation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its best understood with an example...

Lets say `d == 3.1415926` then in your code `a` will end up as `3`. That is truncation.

On the other hand, if `i == 1000` then that is outside the range of `char`. If `char` is `unsigned` the value will wrap around and you will get `1000%256` as the value of `b`. This happens because `int` has a wider range than `char`, hence this conversion is called narrowing.

Answer (score 0):

```
double d=2.345;
int a = d; // a is 2 now, so the number 2.345 is truncated
```

As for `int` to `char`, `char` has size of 1 byte, while `int` has 4 bytes (assuming 32 bit), so you would be "narrowing" variable `i`.

It could be just about english :) You can look up the words in a dictionary so it may be clearer.